# Reading cookie in IE with <img>

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

Visitors on my site (domain_foo.com) get a cookie when visiting. On the site boo_domain.com there is this tag < img src="http://www.domain_foo.com/readCookie.aspx >. 
When a user visits boo_domain the readCookie.aspx on domain_foo.com will be accessed and I'm now allowed to read the domain_foo cookie for all browsers except IE. The Context.Request.Cookies is simply just empty in IE. Can you guys please help me out?

I've search the entire Internet for answers and all the links in my Google SERP is purple. A lot of the posts are very old and a lot were about accessing a cookie in IE through an iframe with a P3P in the header. It doesn't seem to be the same problem here.

Comment: No one can answer this one?